# Maximizing a likelihood involving integral

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, likelihood

I wish to maximize a likelihood function and the likelihood involves an implicit integral of the parameters to be maximized. What technique should I adopt to solve the maximization? I have so far tried gauss-quadrature and simpson's rule  (1/3, on the basis of suitable assumption) to compute an approximate value of the integral. But, the maximization seems to fail.

Comment: Welcome to CV. It is difficult to guess what may be the issue without additional information (what problems do you encounter? which algorithm are you using?). If the likelihood function does not have a closed form solution, evaluating it numerically should not be a problem, except for slowing down the optimization. I have been using succesfully the adaptive quadrature method (implemented in the function `integrate()` in R) to make a lookup table and speed up the computation of the likelihood.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was using nlm algorithm and optim also. Also, since my integral involves a random variable and 2 parameters (which is intended to be maximised), so I could not understand how to use the integrate command, since it only works on a function of single variable ( the random variate in this case) and using the optimization algorithms requires the parameters to be called for in the integral for a numerical value.

Comment: Suparna, the advice from @Matteo is good and useful.  I looks unlikely you will get better until you edit your post to provide the details of your situation.